# how to remove dynamically created Row in user control in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have created an User control. I am creating dynamically this user control in a Page. I have a button in that control to remove the row which is created dynamically. I am unable to remove the entire Row. 
This is my Xaml:

```
 <Grid Name="grid_usercontrolTypeofFixture" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions >
        <RowDefinition Height="20*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="35*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="35*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50*" />            
        <ColumnDefinition Width="15*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label Grid.Row="0"  Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,5,5,5" Content="Select/Type Fixture Type:" />      

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Margin="10,5,5,5" Text="" Name="txtAuto"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="10,5,5,5" Text="" Name="txt_percentage"/>

    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Margin="10,5,5,5" x:Name="btn_removeRow" Content="" Click="btn_removeRow_Click">
        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Assets/Knob Cancel.png"></ImageBrush>
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
 </Grid>
```

This is My Code Behind:

```
 public int count = 1;
 private void btn_addnew_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var myControl = new UserControlTypeofFixture() { Name = "TypeofFixture" };
        grid_typeFixture.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
        Grid.SetRow(myControl, count);
        grid_typeFixture.Margin = new Thickness(10, 10, 10, 10);
        grid_typeFixture.Children.Add(myControl);
        count++;
    }

  private void btn_removeRow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

               ???            
    }
```

I have some other code to remove the selected row. but its not working.  How can i remove entire row?

Comment: Hi, your question is answered at: WPF Delete Row from grid
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20860193/wpf-delete-row-from-grid. Also, I would recommend as alternative to collapse the row instead of removing it (set the Row Height to 0). Rgds, Alex

Comment: its not an usercontrol..

Comment: I would recommend you use an MVVM pattern like everyone else who uses WPF. Then just remove the bound item from the bound collection. Easy.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can remove your `usercontrol` and `rowdefinition`

```
private void btn_removeRow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var myControl = sender as Button;
            int rowindex = (int)myControl.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);

            foreach (UIElement control in grid_typeFixture.Children)
            {
                var usercontrol = control as UserControlTypeofFixture;
                if (usercontrol != null)
                {
                    int childrowindex = (int)usercontrol.GetValue(Grid.RowProperty);
                    if (childrowindex == rowindex)
                    {
                        grid_typeFixture.Children.Remove(control);
                        grid_typeFixture.RowDefinitions.RemoveAt(childrowindex);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, then try the alternative solution I've mentioned, i.e. set the particular RowDefinition Height to 0: pertinent to your case it should be like the following:

```
 private void btn_removeRow_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    grid_typeFixture.RowDefinitions[2].Height = new GridLength(0);            
 }
```